# Double Apple iD?

Tags: iphone, apple-id

My brother in law has a iPhone 4 i gave to him. I wiped the phone using the restore function in iTunes, and activated by restoring HIS backup form a iPhone 3Gs using my computer.

All is fine, all app updates are running ok on my brother-in-laws Apple-Id. Only if there is an iOS update the darn phone asks for the password linked to MY Apple-Id. Probably has to do something with the fact i used MY computer to activate the phone, and restored the backup i pulled from his 3Gs.

How do i remove MY Id from his phone?

Comment: How did you restore a backup of his phone from your computer? Does he use the same computer?

Answer (score 1):

If it's asking for your Apple ID to update an app, then the app has been purchased on your account. You can't change the Apple ID that an app has been purchased with—instead, delete the app from the device and purchase it again with the Apple ID that you want the app registered to.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new user account on your computer
2. Open iTunes, and sign in with his AppleID
3. Perform a backup (make sure to transfer all purchases)
4. Wipe the device again, and this time activate it with his AppleID
5. Restore as normal

This is technically overkill, but will resolve the issue with a lot less headache.

*If he has any applications that were purchased under your AppleID, they will show up when Transferring Purchases; do not transfer them, and repurchase each one under his account. Watch out also for audiobooks and movies.*